# Android - Kotlin - How to overcome a minimal width limit of a button?

Tags: android, button, kotlin, size

I am trying to manipulate a width of an android button with Kotlin using minSdkVersion 19 or higher (test phone has Android 8.0.0, API 26). When I try to make a button smaller I see that it's width couldn't pass some threshold approximately above 200px.

That's how I create and manipulate a button:

```
val button = Button(this)
button.width = btn_side // btn_side = 175
constraintLayout.addView(button)
```

**What I've already tryed**. Different layouts: TableLayout, ConstraintLayout. I've tryed to set textSize to zero in case if it interfered with button width. Or to replace any button text with null string. I've tryed to apply zero or 10px minWidth to a button. I've played with setPadding button method. I've tryed to assign width via layoutParams property. None of which helped.

What am I missing?

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".GameFieldActivity"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
>
```

*** UPD ***
Someone deleted an answer with possibly useful hint: there might be a way to use different [button constructors](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button). Might be there is a way to pass desired button width through [AttributeSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet).

Comment: Maybe you set minwidth or the button may be constrained by its parent. Layout xml file could tell us.

Comment: Can you show us your xml layout? Is it necessarily for you to create button from code?

Comment: I've added xml of Activity to the main post. Yes, it is necessary for me to create a button from code: I want to make a logic game with a square grid of buttons. The higher difficulty - the more buttons I want to place on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
val button = Button(this)
val layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
    50, // you can set initial width here
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
)
constraintLayout.addView(button, layoutParams)
```

---

Some details:

```
// create a button
val button = Button(this)

// crate a layout params you want this button to be added to ViewGroup with
val layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
)

// add a button to ViewGroup with layout params
constraintLayout.addView(button, layoutParams)

// set initial width
button.layoutParams.width = 50
button.width = 50

// increase width of button for 10 with each click
button.setOnClickListener {
    button.layoutParams.width += 10
    button.width += 10
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. I've placed setOnClickListener part stright after addView method. Android Studio wrote "it: View!" after "{" bracket. This method didn't work with height inside "{}" brackets either.

Comment: Have you clicked on the button?:)

Comment: Uh... Actually I didn't :D Thanks! Now new width applies after button is clicked. Is there a way to apply those conditions without tapping manually?

Comment: I got it! The trick is inside **button.layoutParams.width**! In my case usual **button.width** can be excluded. Thanks again!

Comment: UPD: as I see, width must be changed AFTER **addView** is applied. Othervise app crashes or renders inappropriate width (and so does height).